# How to read different data from table when multiple instance of application are running

Tags: spring-batch, distributed-system, multiple-instances

I have to read all data from the table and then process it.
Now the condition is that since multiple instances of the application are running we have to make sure that each instance gets a unique set of records.

I thought of using hashing technique but since our application is deployed on the cloud we don't know the exact number of instances.